Remove element from list of NamedTuples
Hello I have a list of NamedTuples like this:
from typing import NamedTuple

class Car(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    mileage: int


lst = [Car(name='car_1', mileage=100), Car(name='car_2', mileage=200)]

How can I remove the corresponding tuple from the list if I just have the car name, say car_1 ?
I can create another list by removing, like so:
[namedtup for namedtup  in lst if namedtup.name != "car_1"]

but I want to remove it like list remove() from the original list.

I want to remove it like list remove()  but why?

Find the index you want to remove and use del lst[index] ?

Just add lst =  before the list comprehension if you want to modify lst. Or lst[:] =  to modify in-place and affect other references to the list.

There's a working example you can try at this link.

It is a common misconception that removing an item from a list is somehow more efficient than creating a new filtered list with the undesired items not included. In most cases, it is not. When you create the 'new' list with [namedtup for namedtup  in lst if namedtup.name != "car_1"] the items that are 'copied' to the new list are actually not copied at all; the new list just refers to the objects in the original list and the reference counts are increased. Conversely, deleting an item in a list may be worse efficiency wise since you now have a hole in memory from the deleted item.

@dawg There's no hole in memory; items following the deleted items are immediately shifted back one position. Memory usage probably isn't affected at all (the array used to store the list simply remains over allocated to make the next append operation fast). But yes, removing an item from the start of the list remains nearly as time-inefficient as simply building a new list.

@chepner: Respectfully, I somewhat disagree on 'hole in memory' potential. If you have a browse at how cPython allocates memory for objects, it has the potential of being on a per object basis with malloc. Once that mem request is released, there is a potential 'hole' in the heap. That will be addressed, perhaps by moving objects, but there is some work to do to do so. It is implementation and version dependent, but it is best to allow Python to manage the memory rather than micromanage by doing individual deletions...

@dawg That has nothing to do with how a list object itself manages the array allocated to store references to list elements.

@dawg Any why are you linking to the Mercurial repository? Development moved to GitHub over 7 years ago.

Not an answer, but if you have to do this more often, it might be worth changing the data structure to a dictionary, mapping car names to car objects (assuming names are unique).

I am going to assume you do want to remove it from the original list. But don't want to recreate it(lst).
# list  of Named tuples
lst = [Car(name='car_1', mileage=100), Car(name='car_2', mileage=200)]

# find the matching tuple
car_to_remove = next((car for car in lst if car.name == 'car_1'), None)

# if it exists remove
if car_to_remove:
    lst.remove(car_to_remove)

print(lst)  
[Car(name='car_2', mileage=200)]


If you want to delete a "Car" element by its name, you can create a custom class with modified logic for removing elements.
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyList(list):
    def remove(self, a):
        for x in self:
            if x.name == a:
                super().remove(x)
                break

class Car(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    mileage: int

lst = MyList([Car(name="car_1", mileage=100), Car(name="car_2", mileage=200)])
lst.remove("car_1")

print(lst) # [Car(name='car_2', mileage=200)]


Do not modify a list while you're iterating over it. Consider what happens if your MyList construction looks like this: lst = MyList([Car(name="car_1", mileage=100), Car(name="car_1", mileage=200), Car(name="car_2", mileage=200)]) You will notice that MyList still contains one NamedTuple where car.name is equal to "car_1"

You can use a list comprehension to find the first car named car_1 in the lst and remove it using remove() method:
lst.remove([car for car in lst if car.name == 'car_1'][0])

To avoid iterating over the whole list, you can use next like this:
lst.remove(next(car for car in lst if car.name == 'car_1', None))


In principle, the source list (lst) could contain more than one NamedTuple where car.name equals "car_1". Also, there may not be any NamedTuples where car.name equals "car_1". Therefore, this code will only work if there's exactly one occurence where car.name == "car_1". In the latter case, an IndexError will be raised. Using a list comprehension to build a new list is a superior approach

I think OP implies that they are working with a list where at most one car has a given name, so in this case "exactly 1 car" is basically the same as "at least one car". (But then, OP should probably use a dict that maps car names to Car objects instead of a list.) I agree this needs a try statement if there is no car with the given name.

@SIGHUP the OP clearly says they want to use it like remove, and those you have listed are exactly how list.remove behaves. It removes the first occurrence and will raise an error if the item is not in the list. This is clearly not the best way to do this, but it is close enough to what the OP asks, and only in one line.
